# How to add the click attach event dynamically

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to attach the click event dynamically using JavaScript. My sample code is given below.

```
require(["dijit/form/ToggleButton", "dojo/dom-construct"], function (ToggleButton, domConstruct) { 
    var newButton = new ToggleButton({
        showLabel: true,
        checked: false,
        onChange: function (val) { frame(this); },
        label: item.getAttribute('label')
    }, item.getAttribute('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using dojo 1.8+ you can use `Widget#on` to connect to events after the widget is created.

```
var newButton = new ToggleButton({
    showLabel: true,
    checked: false,
    label: item.getAttribute('label')
}, item.getAttribute('id'));

newButton.on('change',function(){
    console.log('onChange event called');
});

newButton.on('click',function(){
    console.log('click event called');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use button id attribute to attach click event
like

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){

//code goes here
})
```

where buttonid is id attribute of your button

Comment: This question is not about jQuery but it's about a Dojo widget.